# Apply CSS for a specific field on Formstack

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout, formstack

I was trying to span the checkbox field in 3 columns on this form - https://learningcurve.formstack.com/forms/list_of_banks\

So, I wrote

```
.fsBody .fsForm .fsFieldCell {
    column-count:3;
}
```

But it spans all the similar fields into 3 columns. I need to span only one specific field to span to 3 columns. I believe that is something to do with the field id. How do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the example you have linked and it seems you changed the wrong element to 3 columns.

Try this code instead and see if it works for your issue.

```
.fsBody .fsForm .fsFieldCell .fieldset-content{
  column-count:3;
}
```

Comment: Hey, it worked! Thanks a lot.

However, the form has lost its responsiveness. I want the columns to shrink to 1 when it is viewed on mobile. Can you help, please?

Comment: you will have to use media queries. Define how many columns you want for the mobile layout. More info at this link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp